What is the difference between await method(), await method().ConfigureAwait(true), and await method().ConfigureAwait(false) in C#?
I'm trying to understand the differences between the following three usages of the await keyword in C#:

await method();
await method().ConfigureAwait(true);
await method().ConfigureAwait(false);

From my research, I understand that it has something to do with how asynchronous continuations are handled, particularly in relation to synchronization contexts. However, I am still unclear on the exact differences and implications of each usage.
Could someone elaborate on:
What exactly happens in each case?
How does ConfigureAwait(true) differ from ConfigureAwait(false)?
When and why should one prefer ConfigureAwait(false) over the await method()?
Are there specific scenarios (e.g., UI applications vs. server applications) where one approach is recommended over the others?
Any detailed explanation or examples would be greatly appreciated!

There are a lot of duplicates for this. A lot. It's also thoroughly documented. There's no single recommendation, it depends on what you're doing, which is also documented. true is the default so there's no point in asking about ConfigureAwait(true) at all.

The method's documentation already gives a short explanation and links to the far more thorough ConfigureAwait FAQ.

And because ConfigureAwait(true) is default, we only have two usages

The guidance is to use ConfiureAwait(false) in libraries, or your own library-like code, to avoid forcing a continuation mode on an application. In application code using await alone is enough unless you really want to avoid going back to the UI thread/sync context. Web and console apps (except Blazor Server) don't have a UI thread or synchronization context so ConfigureAwait(false) has no effect.

Also worth reading this post from Stephen Cleary

In most cases you're going to use async/await just as is.

Example: Console app (taken from the LinqPad examples):
async Task Main()
{
    "Starting".Dump();  
    int result = await myLongRunningTask();
    result.Dump();  
    "Finished".Dump();
}

async Task<int> myLongRunningTask()
{
    // Simulate an asynchronous operation that takes 3 seconds
    await Task.Delay (3000);
    return 42; // so long Douglas Adams, and thanks for all the books! :-)
}

Normally you would just use it like that. But if you have scenarios, where you have a good reason to use ConfigureAwait, there is a quite good description here describing what it does and what it can be used for.
Most of the following is taken from that FAQ to give you an idea, but please check out the link above, because there is much more:


Why would I want to use ConfigureAwait(false)?
When you perform an asynchronous operation using async and await, the operation is offloaded to a different thread or task, allowing the calling thread to continue executing other work. Once the asynchronous operation is complete, the rest of the async method (the continuation from the original context) needs to be executed.
ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false) is used to avoid forcing the callback to be invoked on the original context or scheduler. This has a few benefits:
Improving performance
There is a cost to queueing the callback rather than just invoking it, both because there’s extra work (and typically extra allocation) involved, but also because it means certain optimizations we’d otherwise like to employ in the runtime can’t be used (we can do more optimization when we know exactly how the callback will be invoked, but if it’s handed off to an arbitrary implementation of an abstraction, we can sometimes be limited).
Reliability benefits (avoiding deadlocks)
It can prevent deadlocks that are possible when the original context is blocked waiting for the task to complete, but the task is also waiting for the context to be free to continue.
Consider a library method that uses await on the result of some network download. You invoke this method and synchronously block waiting for it to complete, such as by using .Wait() or .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult() off of the returned Task object. Now consider what happens if your invocation of it happens when the current SynchronizationContext is one that limits the number of operations that can be running on it to 1, whether explicitly via something like the MaxConcurrencySynchronizationContext shown earlier, or implicitly by this being a context that only has one thread that can be used, e.g. a UI thread (the section Regarding "original context" below).
General-purpose library code
Code that is designed to be reused across different applications and is not specific to any particular application type (like a UI application). In such code, you typically don't know or care about the synchronization context, so it's safer and more efficient to use ConfigureAwait(false).

Why would I want to use ConfigureAwait(true)?
You wouldn’t, unless you were using it purely as an indication that you were purposefully not using ConfigureAwait(false) (e.g. to silence static analysis warnings or the like). ConfigureAwait(true) does nothing meaningful. When comparing await task with await task.ConfigureAwait(true), they’re functionally identical. If you see ConfigureAwait(true) in production code, you can delete it without ill effect.


In the simple example, instead of
     await Task.Delay(3000);

you could also write
     await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);

but it will make no difference in a console application, because there is no synchronization context. To see and understand the impact, check out the section Regarding "original context" below.
However, it's a good practice to use it in library code to avoid potential deadlocks and performance issues related to context capturing.
Please note that when you use ConfigureAwait(false), you must ensure that the code after the await does not need to run on the original context, such as updating the UI in a desktop application.

Regarding "original context"
"It is the SynchronizationContext instance that was captured at the await point, by reading the static SynchronizationContext.Current property. The async/await machinery captures automatically the context whenever an incomplete task is awaited, and invokes the continuation on the captured context." - Theodor Zoulias
What "original context" means can be explained if you have a button on a WinForms application.
This example was chosen, because there you have one single UI Thread updating the application forms, buttons and other controls.
Windows Forms has a SynchronizationContext-derived type that overrides Post to do the equivalent of Control.BeginInvoke; that means any calls to its Post method will cause the delegate to be invoked at some later point on the thread associated with that relevant Control, aka “the UI thread” (described in more detail in the section What is a SynchronizationContext?).
The following click event handlers are doing something (here: a simple delay as implemented in myLongRunningTask()), and one of the buttons is using .ConfigureAwait(false), the other one not (using default behaviour which is equal to .ConfigureAwait(true)):
private async void BtnWithoutConfigureAwait_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await myLongRunningTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // This line will throw an exception because it's not running on the UI thread
    lblResult.Text = "Completed without ConfigureAwait";
}

private async void BtnWithConfigureAwait_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await myLongRunningTask(); // Implicitly ConfigureAwait(true)
    // This line will work fine because it's running on the UI thread
    lblResult.Text = "Completed with ConfigureAwait";
}

The button handler BtnWithConfigureAwait_Click works as expected, while the other one BtnWithoutConfigureAwait_Click will throw an exception, because the original context which is the UI thread of the application, is not available when continuing after the await (hence, lblResult.Text cannot be changed in that handler).
In the task myLongRunningTask() instead of a delay, you could think about any task that takes some time, such as a stored procedure running or a Mandelbrot picture rendering.

"is used to avoid forcing the callback to be invoked on the original context or scheduler." -- The term original might be confusing here. You might want to add a footnote in the answer, to clarify what original means.

@TheodorZoulias - good hint, I added some more explanation hoping it is clearer now what "original context" means.

Hmm, honestly I don't think that currently (revision 5) the meaning of the original context has been clarified. If someone doesn't already know what a SynchronizationContext is and how it relates to threads, they will be left confused by your answer. Explaining the ConfigureAwait is not an easy task, so if you decide to go for it you should be prepared to put maximum effort on the explanation. Otherwise your answer won't be helpful for the people who need to be helped.

@TheodorZoulias - You are right, and I thought about it for a while, then I found a simple example which illustrates it (I hope). Let me know!

​Here is how I would have explained the meaning of original context: “It is the SynchronizationContext instance that was captured at the await point, by reading the static SynchronizationContext.Current property. The async/await machinery captures automatically the context whenever an incomplete task is awaited, and invokes the continuation on the captured context.” I have no idea if this explanation would be more useful than yours. This mechanism is particularly complex and hard to explain.

@TheodorZoulias - It is a good explanation that you provided. And yes, to understand async/await in depth is hard, because it hides so much complexity you would otherwise have to think about (and implement!) as a developer.

@TheodorZoulias - I have embedded your explanation.

No idea who downvoted - but please leave a comment telling me what you did not like so I am able to improve the answer.

Don't be too concerned about 1 downvote. This can happen for "meta" reasons, and not because your answer is flawed. I would suggest to ignore the vote, and hope/expect that eventually it will be balanced with the upvotes.
